# Error running meteor. Cannot find or execute file

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I am having issues running `meteor` on my machine. Recently pulled the code from my repo to a new computer, but whenever I run the meteor command I get

```
/Users/moon/.meteor/meteor: line 143: /Users/moon/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.14rknqp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: No such file or directory

/Users/moon/.meteor/meteor: line 143: exec: /Users/moon/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.8.0_2.14rknqp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/bin/node: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the meteor version of the project and which versions are installed on your machine?

Comment: @Jankapunkt doing a "cat .meteor/release" gives me 1.8.0.2 I cannot do a meteor --version because meteor command does not work at all, gives the same error

Comment: `cannot do a meteor --version because meteor command does not work at all` sounds to me like Meteor is either not installed or not installed correctly (wrong permissions etc.). Does it run if you re-install from https://meteor.com ?